# Linear application

Tags: matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear application and let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

We know that $\operatorname{Im} f=\langle(1,1,3), (0,1,1)\rangle$ and that

$$2f(e_2)-f(e_3)=e_1-e_2+e_3$$

Which is the matrix associated to $f$ with respect the canonical basis?

In order to have the matrix I should know $f(e_1), f(e_2), f(e_3)$ but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

*Assume* that

$$fe_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;\;fe_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;fe_3=\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{pmatrix}$$

Observe that we have already

$$\text{Im}\,f\subset\left\langle\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\;\right\rangle$$

Now, we're given

$$e_1-e_2+e_3=\begin{pmatrix}1\\\!-1\\1\end{pmatrix}=2fe_2-fe_3=\begin{pmatrix}\!-u_1\\2-u_2\\2-u_3\end{pmatrix}\;\implies\;fe_3=\begin{pmatrix}\!-1\\3\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

and observe that

$$fe_3\in\left\langle\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\;\right\rangle\implies\text{Im}\,f=\left\langle\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\;\right\rangle\implies$$

$$[f]_e=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\!-1\\1&1&3\\3&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!! My question is...

Comment: Why I have to put $f(e_1)=(1,1,3)$ and $f(e_2)=(0,1,1)$? I could do also the viceversa?

Comment: And what if I put $f(e_3)=(0,1,1)$ for istance?

Comment: the linear application is not unique?

Comment: Yes, you could do otherwise, and no: the linear application isn't unique. Yet we **have to respect** the fact that the image of the application *is given* ...